# Angular CDK and pass values to component in DomPortalHost

Tags: angular, portal, angular-cdk

i have the following service

```
@Injectable()
export class PService {
   private loadPComponent: ComponentPortal<PComponent>;
   private bodyPortalHost: DomPortalHost;

   constructor(private appRef: ApplicationRef,
               private  componentFactoryResolver: 
                       ComponentFactoryResolver,
               private injector: Injector) {
      this.loadPComponent = new ComponentPortal(PComponent);
   }
   instance(elementRef: Element) {
      this.bodyPortalHost = new DomPortalHost(elementRef, 
           this.componentFactoryResolver, this.appRef, this.injector);
   }
   show() {
      const componentRef: ComponentRef<PComponent> = 
                 this.bodyPortalHost.attach(this.loadPComponent);
   }
   hide() {
      this.bodyPortalHost.detach();
   }
}
```

So, I have a Component calle "PComponent" and from that service i create dinamically the component
the class have two method
instance - that pass the Element of the component that call the service
show - that attach the PComponent already "created"

all work well, Portal is a fantastic solution!!
but my PComponent have an HTML template with some variables, like for example,

> {{ imageURL }}

that should be an image url and display that image into a div content in PComponent.
**The Question**
How i can pass the imageURL string into the service or into the component?

thanks in advance

Comment: What's the problem with it? If you managed to write code that is used ComponentPortal then it should be easy for you)

Comment: Hi @yurzui i don't understand your answer, sorry :-)
If i inject that service to another Component how is possible to pass values to the PComponent? that's my question and my problem, maybe is a stupid question, but is my first time with Angular CDK and maybe i need some help :-)

Comment: `ComponentRef` has `instance` property. Can it help you?

Comment: Good approach @yurzui, i do it and work, but the console return the following error:
"ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null: undefined'. Current value: 'null: testing text'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?"

this is because i instance the componentRef and after i will call the instance and i will change the value variable.
did you know if is possible to do that without that error?
thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @yurzui maybe i have to do something with a specific Injector, what do you think?

Comment: Can you reproduce the error on stackblitz?

Comment: This is a problem from Angular.
this is because the component injected is after child.
is possible to solve with trick.
in the component where you inject the service you have to enclose the service call into a Promise
Promise.resolve().then(() => {
         this.yourInjectedService.....
});

this is a temporal fix, but it's work
thanks @yurzui for your help and pacience

Answer (score 5):

This is the answer

this is the Pcomponent code, this component should be created dinamically from another component.
**p.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-p',
    templateUrl: './p.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./p.component.css']
})
export class PComponent implements OnInit {
    name: string = '';
    constructor(@Inject(CONTAINER_DATA) public componentData: any) { 
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.componentData.data.test);
    }
}
```

so we have to inject the CONTAINER_DATA InjectionToken, from that variable is possible to get the data passed from other components.
The CONTAINER_DATA variable is created in the service file.
**p.service.ts**

```js
import {ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, Injectable, InjectionToken, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {CONTAINER_DATA, PComponent} from './p.component';
import {
    ComponentPortal,
    DomPortalHost, PortalInjector
} from '@angular/cdk/portal';
export const CONTAINER_DATA = new InjectionToken<{}>('CONTAINER_DATA');
@Injectable()
export class PService {
    private loadPComponent: ComponentPortal<PComponent>;
    private bodyPortalHost: DomPortalHost;
    constructor(private appRef: ApplicationRef,
        private  componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private injector: Injector) { }
    instance(elementRef: Element, data) {
        this.loadPComponent = new ComponentPortal(PComponent, null, 
            this.createInjector({data}));
        this.bodyPortalHost = new DomPortalHost(elementRef, 
            this.componentFactoryResolver, this.appRef, this.injector);
    }
    show() {
        const componentRef: ComponentRef<PComponent> = 
        this.bodyPortalHost.attach(this.loadPComponent);
    }
    createInjector(dataToPass): PortalInjector {
        const injectorTokens = new WeakMap();
        injectorTokens.set(CONTAINER_DATA, dataToPass);
        return new PortalInjector(this.injector, injectorTokens);
    }
    hide() {
        this.bodyPortalHost.detach();
    }
}
```

So, in the service we use @angular/cdk/portal to get the PComponent instance.
the *instance()* and the *show()* methods are the methods to call from an external Component.
the *createInjector()* is the method that create the *Injector* that help us to pass datas to the component ( PComponent ).
So it's time to use our service in another component.
**example.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-example',
    templateUrl: './example.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./example.component.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('bpage', {read: ElementRef}) tref: ElementRef;
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private pService: 
         PService, private contentService: ContentService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        Promise.resolve().then(() => {
           this.pService.instance(this.tref.nativeElement, {'test': 
            'prueba'});
    }
}
```

This component have, in the html template a tag like that:

```
<div #bpage></div>
```

in this tag should be charged the content coming from the PComponent and injected from PService.
In the OnInit method we have to enclose the service call into a Promise, this avoid the following error:

*ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null: undefined'. Current value: 'null: testing text'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?*

After a page refresh you will see the content of PComponent automatically generated and published in the bpage tag

hope it help you

Comment: I don't see such error and I also can pass data through show method. I know that angular material uses WeakMap to build injector for dynamic component